# Why is l-box breaking Purecss.io grids?

Tags: html, css

Can't seem to figure out why once I add the l-box class to my div elements it breaks the grid in Purecss.io

I'm following the template here http://purecss.io/layouts/marketing/  but as you can see in my codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/axAGJ the addition of l-box royally screws up the 4 column pattern but seems to work just find in the template.

I inspected the elements on both mine and the template and the issues I see is that the width of the div itself is bigger on my rendition but I don't know what's causing that to happen or how to change it.

I've tried adjusting my font sizes and the elements still stack incorrectly.

Template div width 277.500px
My div width 330.250px

```
.l-box {
padding: 1em;
}
```

Comment: When you're asking a question you should be more technical and have more of an understanding of your code.. Also, why do you even need padding? It makes elements in HTML bigger than you'd expect. It works fine without it in my case.

Comment: Without the padding elements are squished next to each other, especially an image next to text.

Comment: Also an example of how to be more technical would be great, so that I can become better at asking questions.

Comment: Well okay, look. How well do you understand Html and css? This seems like a complicated task, more than it may appear to be. Any ways, your problem is the size of the divs. You set them to be "25%" each which means that all four of them are 100% together. That means you won't have any room for padding because it will make each element larger and thus pushing your last "box" down.

Comment: I understand that, however so is the template. It's set up the same way 25% for each div but they also have the padding and still manage to get all four on one line. That's where I'm having issues. I'm replicating the same thing but getting different results with not real idea as to why it's happening

Comment: Where does it use padding? Does this solve your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/75Kez/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57879/discussion-between-lemony-andrew-and-kayhart).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem you were encountering was the padding effecting your boxes to be to large. To overcome this, there is a css attribute called `box-sizing:`.

The [box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) property allows you to define certain elements to fit an area in a certain way. So, by setting this property to border-box you will have content, padding and border fit inside your div instead of push out making it larger than you'd expect.

Be careful though, as this property is somewhat new and may need fall back for people using older browsers.

Usage example:

```
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This will make sure the padding on `l-box` occurs inside the div.

Comment: There should be a work around you can fall back to and I'll get to that soon.